# Terraform quickest way to import multiple resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My Terraform state file is messedup. Resources are already available on AWS. When I run terraform apply command I am getting multiple "Already Exists" error same as below.

```
aws_autoscaling_group.mysql-asg: Error creating AutoScaling Group: AlreadyExists: AutoScalingGroup by this name already exists - A group with the name int-mysql-asg already exists
```

When I do terraform import then it goes away. but I have hundreds of resources which is giving error. What is the best way to sync terraform state and make terraform apply successful?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Terraforming](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming)

It's a Ruby project that states "Export existing AWS resources to Terraform style (tf, tfstate)"